# Is ‘(stroll with) a spring in one’s heels” a popular English idiom?

Tags: idioms

I came across the phrase, “strolled over to a place with a spring in his heels” in Jeffery Archer’s novel, Kane & Abel, which I started to read a few months ago and still in the midway.
It appears in the following sentence:

> “He (Abel Rosnovski, one of the two leading characters) was certain
>   the banker would not have found a buyer, but nonetheless he strolled
>   over to the Continental Trust **with a spring in his heels**. He liked the
>   idea of being the manager of the best hotel in Chicago.”

Though I can easily surmise that ‘stroll with a spring in one’s heels’ means to stroll lightheartedly and cheerfully -We express this feeling as 小躍りして歩く‐walk cheerfully like dancing in Japanese-, I don’t find this phrase in any of OALD, online OED, CED, and Merriam-Webster.

Google NGram doesn’t register “a spring in one’s heels,” but it registers “a spring in my step,” of which currency restarted around circ 1930 following a long hiatus after its short emergence during 1840 through 1980.

I also found the definition of “a spring in one's step” as “(n.uc. / idiomatic) enthusiasm, energy or a positive outlook or cheerful attitude” in wikitionar, and the following example in glossfree.com/ :

> “I've made the decision to March forward into March **with a spring in
>   my step** and a smile in my heart for many days of living life to its
>   every emotion and experience that lies ahead and enjoy it! Life's too
>   short to get bogged.”

Is “(do with) a spring in one’s step” a popular English idiom, and “stroll with a spring in his heels” is just a variation coined by Jeffery Archer?

Comment: I've always heard it as "a spring in his step"

Answer (score 4):

No, "spring in his heels" is much less common than "spring in his step" ... 
[image]

Comment: But consider also the expression "spring-heeled" which clearly predates Archer. I suspect that he (deliberately or inadvertently) combined two forms.